# IntegrityError at /signup UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

I'm trying to make an authentication system using Django using only 3 fields for SignUp (username & email & password ) and 2 fields for sign in ( username & password )
I think that the error that I get has relation to database, which I haven't used my models file yet, I don't know where the problem is coming from, is it from the signup function or the signing function

```
    IntegrityError at /signup
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username
Exception Location: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 423, in execute
Python Executable:  C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\greenaftech',
 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Sat, 30 Apr 2022 00:24:12 +0000
```

**this is my views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,"website/index.html")




def signup(request):

    if request.method=="POST":
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        myuser= User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
        myuser.save()
        messages.success(request,"Your Account has been created.")
        return redirect('signin')


    return render(request,"website/signup.html")



def signin(request):
    if request.method=='POST':

        usern=request.POST.get('username')
        passs=request.POST.get('password')
        

        user=authenticate(username=usern,password=passs)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            userr=user.username
            return render(request,"website/index.html",{'username':userr})
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Wrong Infos")
            return redirect('home') 

    return render(request,"website/signin.html")



def signout(request):
    pass
```

**and these are my URLs.py** :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('',views.home,name='home'),
   path('signup',views.signup,name='signup'),
   path('signin',views.signin,name='signin'),
   path('signout',views.signout,name='signout'),
]
```

Comment: and by the way, when I create an account using my forms, it gets created into the admin panel, but still, the error is getting showed

Answer (score 0):

That error would be incurred if you try and create two users with the same username, with your uath_user model's username field having a unique=True constraint (which prevents two records having the same value in that field).

Note that if you use User.objects.create(...) as opposed to User(username="username"...) it will automatically save the new record, so myUser.save() may be trying to replicate that creation, creating the constraint issue, while still allowing you to see the item in admin

Comment: I mean , where should I pass that argument (  unique = True ) ?

Comment: Immediately after I posted, I noticed you had called save after create, which might be the cause of the error. I have added to the answer to reflect this. I think the constraint is fine where it is.

Comment: do you have any solution to this ?

Comment: You just need to remove the myuser.save() line as it is redundant in this case

Comment: I tried that but still the same issue

Comment: I can't see anything else obviously wrong - make sure you have restarted your server and aren't entering any username or other uniquely constrained fields that already exist for users. You can add checks for this in your view as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67750437/18799377